# Is there a resource that lists airport taxes?

Tags: online-resources, airports, fees-and-charges

When spending frequent flyer miles, I have to pay the local taxes. Since airports consider the competition they sometimes lower the ticket price to fit the competition from an airport 400 km away. Sometimes it is more cost efficient to just pay a ticket and use the miles on a cheaper airport.

So far I have always searched for airport taxes based on trial and error. It would be quite convenient if I could just consult a resource with all taxes applied on a given airport. Does such a resource exist?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

It seems that the page I provided below in my old answer only shows one type of the taxes and not the full airport taxes (as mentioned in a comment by Doc). So my answer at best is partially correct.

Anyway, the only resource I found for the full taxes is again from IATA's website ([IATA List of Ticket and Airport Taxes and Fees](http://www.iata.org/services/finance/Pages/tax-list.aspx)), which is a paid PDF file/CD Rom and it costs ($2,671.00), this is too much for such a resource, and most likely the sum of taxes you will pay for the coming 10 years will be less than this amount. Anyway, searching Google did return this PDF file from another websites, I do not know if downloading it will be legal or not, but it is there!

**Another option is:** in [Kayak.com](http://Kayak.com), after selecting a fare, it will show the sum of taxes to be paid, this sum will include the airport taxes, along with other taxes so it is the closest figure you can get, for free.

---

**Old answer**

As usual, IATA's website provide such information. The [Customs, Currency & Airport Tax regulations](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations.htm) page provides a lot of information including airport taxes in the selected country (you have to click "more about tax" to see full airport tax information). Here is an example of airport tax in Indonesia:

[image: tax]

Comment: This appears to only list taxes that must be paid at the airport, and not those that are included in the ticket price.  eg, for both Australia and the US it states "No airport tax is levied on passengers upon embarkation at the airport", yet both these countries do have departure and/or arrival taxes that can add up to (in the case of Australia) well over $100 per trip.

Comment: @Doc you are right, I tested Indonesia only and it was correct for Indonesia (because Indonesia has no taxes included in tickets and only the one paid by passengers). Anyway answer is updated now.